# Multiple inserts to different tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert records into 2 different tables based on the info from 1 form. However I am getting a syntax error. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO
        " . DB_PFIX . "pages (
            title,
            url,
            content,
            parent,
            created_by,
            created_date,
            published
        ) VALUES (
            '" . $_POST["title"] . "',
            '" . $_POST["url"] . "',
            '" . $_POST["content"] . "',
            '" . $_POST["parent"] . "',
            '" . $user_id . "',
            '" . $time . "',
            '" . $_POST["published"] . "'
        );
    INSERT INTO
        " . DB_PFIX . "links (
            name,
            function
        ) VALUES (
            '" . $_POST["url"] . "',
            'pages'
        );
";
```

This is the error message I get:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO links ( name, function ) VALUES ( '' at line 19
```

Comment: You can try removing the semicolons.  But my guess is that you won't be able to do this.  You'll probably need to start a transaction, run two inserts separately, then commit them.  What are you using to interface with your database.  PDO?

Comment: you cant do that with `mysql_query()`

Comment: Start a transaction then do 2 inserts. I doubt that you can't do it like you tried.

Comment: same error message Cypher. the mysql manual shows this as an example

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,23),(2,34),(4,33);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (8,26),(6,29);

Comment: What is the rationale behind wanting them all in one statement? Btw I do not think you can insert into multiple tables using single insert.

Comment: Not asked, but it should be pointed out that, respecting the values of $_POST, is a no no.  You should do filtering on the values provided, never trust user input.

Comment: What does your final query look like *after* it has been processed?

Comment: I know aztechy. I will get there eventually once the function works. However this is in admin area not public user area. But I will trim results and use `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: ***WARNING*** Your code is very vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Consider using prepared stamements.

Comment: I tried doing a transaction by putting `START TRANSACTION;` before the query and `COMMIT;` after the query. Same error message.

Comment: I KNOW IT IS VULNERABLE TO SQL INJECTION AND OTHER STUFF. I WILL VERIFY DATA AT A LATER POINT ONCE IT IS FUNCTIONAL

Comment: @CoryNickerson - lol...I hear you :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't multiple tables per se; the problem is that, by default, the PHP mysqli interface **disallows** multiple statements in a single statement string.

With mysqli, it's possible to enable an option to allow this. But be aware that this option throws open a wide door for some nasty SQL Injection. The default setting (allowing only a single SQL statement per statement string) doesn't prevent SQL Injection; but it does shut the door on a whole boatload of SQL Injection nastiness.)

There's no need to repeat the documentation, available here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

With that option enabled, it's possible to submit multiple SQL statements in a single statement string.

I will again repeat, enabling multiple statements does throw open the door to "Little Bobby Tables"-style nastiness ala

[XKCD: Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

(It's not clear whether you are using mysqli or PDO, but given that this statement does not include bind parameter placeholders, I'm venturing that this is not a prepared statement, so it's likely you are using an interface other than PDO.)

Answer (score 0):

Separate them into two separate queries

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO
        " . DB_PFIX . "pages (
            title,
            url,
            content,
            parent,
            created_by,
            created_date,
            published
        ) VALUES (
            '" . $_POST["title"] . "',
            '" . $_POST["url"] . "',
            '" . $_POST["content"] . "',
            '" . $_POST["parent"] . "',
            '" . $user_id . "',
            '" . $time . "',
            '" . $_POST["published"] . "'
        );";
mysql_query($query);
$query = "
    INSERT INTO
        " . DB_PFIX . "links (
            name,
            function
        ) VALUES (
            '" . $_POST["url"] . "',
            'pages'
        );
";
mysql_query($query);
```

However, you really ought to look in to using PDO to build your queries as you should never trust input from the $_POST in your queries to be safe.  This is extremely hackable.

Comment: I am sure the OP knows that. He is checking if it can be done in single query.

Comment: Yes however if there is no other way to do it in 1 query I may have to do it this way after all...

Comment: @CoryNickerson- that is the only way AFAIK. Also I think it might be a potential security risk if it were possible.